# Decomposition results for locally commutative semigroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups-and-monoids

Every finite abelian group is the direct product of its cyclic groups of prime order, and every commutative monoid divides a product of its cyclic submonoids. Could these results generalized to locally commutative semigroups? Here a semigroup is called *locally commutative* if for every idempotent $e \in S$ the semigroup $eSe$ is commutative.

Comment: What do you have in mind? If you take a locally trivial semigroup ($eSe = e$ for each idempotent $e$), how do you want to decompose it?

Comment: I do not believe that there is any nice decomposition result for locally commutative semigroups.  Even the natural guess for a semigroup product decomposition, $\mathbf {Com}\ast \mathbf D$, doesn't hold by a result of Therien and Weiss.

Comment: I had in mind some decomposition in easy semigroups whose recongizable languages are easy to describe for a variety correspondence result, specifically I am looking for a variety of $\omega$-semigroups recognizing languages of the form $\bigcup B_n(\xi) = \{ \eta \in X^{\omega} : \xi[1\ldots n] = \eta[1\ldots n] \land F_n(\xi) = F_n(\eta) \}$ where $F_n(\xi)$ denotes the factors of length $n$ of $\xi$.

Comment: For finite words it seems like you would be looking at local semilattices, which do have a semidirect product decomposition. I don't really know the infinite word version but perhaps @J.-E.Pin can answer that.